# ¿Como checar varios links de descarga directa activos en php?

Tags: php

Hola amigos mi duda es que estoy tratando de crear un testador de enlaces de descarga directa en linea solo quiero que que me diga que esta online ayuda por favor..

Answer (score 1):

Una forma ligera es usar el método [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) que nos ayuda a obtener las cabeceras de respuesta de una petición HTTP.

El código para una petición correcta es 200, así que buscamos ese valor en las cabeceras.

```
function existe_recurso($url){
   $cabeceras=get_headers($url);
   return stripos($cabeceras[0],"200 OK")?true:false;
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo voy a probar